# Why does ff still store data in RAM?

Tags: r, memory-management

Using the [ff package of R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html), I imported a csv file into a ffdf object, but was surprised to find that the object occupied some 700MB of RAM. Isn't ff supposed to keep data on disk rather than in RAM? Did I do something wrong? I am a novice in R. Any advices are appreciated. Thanks.

```
> training.ffdf <- read.csv.ffdf(file="c:/temp/training.csv", header=T)
> # [Edit: the csv file is conceptually a large data frame consisting
> # of heterogeneous types of data --- some integers and some character
> # strings.]
>
> # The ffdf object occupies 718MB!!!
> object.size(training.ffdf)
753193048 bytes
Warning messages:
1: In structure(.Internal(object.size(x)), class = "object_size") :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In structure(.Internal(object.size(x)), class = "object_size") :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
>
> # Shouldn't biglm be able to process data in small chunks?!
> fit <- biglm(y ~ as.factor(x), data=training.ffdf)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 18.5 Mb
```

**Edit:** I followed the advice of Tommy, omitted the object.size call and looked at Task Manager (I ran R on a Windows XP machine with 4GB RAM). I ffsave the object, closed R, reopened it, and loaded the data from file. The problem prevailed:

```
> library(ff); library(biglm)
> # At this point RGui.exe had used up 26176 KB of memory
> ffload(file="c:/temp/trainingffimg")
> # Now 701160 KB
> fit <- biglm(y ~ as.factor(x), data=training.ffdf)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 18.5 Mb
```

I have also tried

```
> options("ffmaxbytes" = 402653184) # default = 804782080 B ~ 767.5 MB
```

but after loading the data, RGui still used up more than 700MB of memory and the biglm regression still issued an error.

Comment: biglm has its own memory handling and lets you pass it data chunk by chunk for updating a model, it's not going to be able to use an ff object. I'd recommend reading the documentation for functions you want to use.

Comment: see ?ff for how to use in conjunction with biglm

Comment: Thanks, @mdsummer. I have read the documentation. Apparently the error in the above biglm line is due to the fact that biglm() expects a data frame, but ffdf is not a data frame. The correct usage should be something like biglm(y ~ as.factor(x), data=training.ffdf[,c(2,5)]). With the column indices, the ffdf will return a data frame. But all these, of course, do not explain why the training.fdff object itself occupies >700MB of memory.

Comment: BTW, I thought the bigglm() function allows you to specify a chunk size, but the biglm() function does not. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide the data in chunks to biglm, see ?biglm.
If you pass a ffdf object instead of a data.frame, you run into one of the following two problems:

1. ffdf is not a data.frame, so something undefined happens
2. the function to which you passed tries to convert ffdf to data.frame by e.g. as.data.frame(ffdf), which easily exhausts your RAM, this likely is what happend to you

Check ?chunk.ffdf for an example of how to pass chunks from ffdf to biglm.

Comment: Or use bigglm.ffdf from package ffbase, this chunks it for you.

Answer (score 2):

The `ff` package uses memory mapping to just load parts of the data into memory as needed.

But it seems that by calling `object.size`, you actually force loading the whole thing into memory! That's what the warning messages seem to indicate...

So don't do that... Use Task Manager (Windows) or the top command (Linux) to see how much memory the R process actually uses before and after you've loaded the data.

Comment: I don't think it's the call to `object.size` per se, but the fact that they're asking for the size of the _entire_ `training.ffdf` object.  I.e. `object.size(training.ffdf[1,1])` may work... just a guess though.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - Well, it seems to me that `object.size` recursively checks all the objects in the data set, which probably prompts them all to be fully realized (i.e., loaded) in memory first.

Comment: Thanks, Tommy. I omitted the object.size call, but the issue remains. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and posted a question, and there is a possible explanation for your issue. 
When you read a file, character rows are treated as factors, and if there is a lot of unique levels, they will go into RAM. ff seems to load always factor levels into RAM. See this 
answer from jwijffels in my question:

[Loading ffdf data take a lot of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953901/loading-ffdf-data-take-a-lot-of-memory)

best, 
miguel.