# ff object is taking up full memory?

Tags: r, memory-management

**1)** I open RGui, then type `require(ff)`, then without typing anything more into the RConsole I check `Windows Task Manager --> Processes --> RGui.exe` and see a memory allocation of `~30,000K`.

**2)** I go back to RConsole. I type `Data <- read.csv.ffdf(file="filename.csv",row.names=1)`. This .csv file is ~30MB.

**3)** Computer loads the data, and I eyeball the memory allocation to `Rgui.exe` as it loads. The memory increases dramatically to `131,436K` and hovers around there until the .csv file finishes importing into R.

***AFTER*** (not before!) all of this, I'll go

```
 > object.size(Data)
  34510880 bytes
```

which confirms that it's in my memory.

This problem is also found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900898/why-does-ff-still-store-data-in-ram), but the claim in the only answer was that the call to `object.size` was putting it into memory. However I do `object.size` AFTER I witness that my memory gets filled with this object. Also, upon calling object.size there is ZERO lag, so it's impossible that my computer just puts 30MB into my memory instantaneously with 0 lag. Loading a 30MB .csv into memory takes like 60 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

A 30 Mb csv file should be no problem to read into R without using ffdf. You probably have a lot of columns, which does not play well with ffdf. The following example runs fine, and does not use the amount of memory you say:

```
spam = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(10e7), 1000, 2500)) # 76 mb
write.table(spam, file = "spam.csv", sep = ",")
spam2 = read.table("spam.csv", sep = ",")
```

`ffdf` is designed to work with very large csv files (>> 30 mb) with a limited amount of columns. In this case I do not see any reason to use `ffdf`. If you want faster loading, just save the object using `save` which saves in a binary format, load it again with `load`.