# Loading ffdf data take a lot of memory

Tags: r

I am facing a strange problem: 
I save `ffdf` data using

```
save.ffdf()
```

from `ffbase` package and when i load them in a new R session, doing

```
load.ffdf("data.f")
```

it gets loaded into RAM aprox 90% of the memory than the same data as a `data.frame` object in R. 
Having this issue, it does not make a lot of sense to use `ffdf`, isn´t it? 
I can't use `ffsave` because i am working in a server and do not have the zip app on it.

```
packageVersion(ff) # 2.2.10
packageVersion(ffbase) # 0.6.3
```

Any ideas about ?

*[edit] some code example to help to clarify:*

```
data <- read.csv.ffdf(file = fn, header = T, colClasses = classes) 
# file fn is a csv database with 5 columns and 2.6 million rows,
# with some factor cols  and some integer cols. 
data.1 <- data 
save.ffdf(data.1 , dir = my.dir) # my.dir is a string pointing to the file. "C:/data/R/test.f" for example.
```

closing the R session... opening again:

```
load.ffdf(file.name) # file.name is a string pointing to the file. 
#that gives me object data, with class(data) = ffdf.
```

then i have a data object ffdf[5] , and its memory size is almost as big as:

```
data.R <- data[,] # which is a data.frame.
```

*[end of edit]*

***[ SECOND EDIT :: FULL REPRODUCIBLE CODE ::: ]

As my question is not answered yet, and i still find the problem, i give a reproducible example ::

```
dir1 <- 'P:/Projects/RLargeData';
setwd(dir1);
library(ff)
library(ffbase)

memory.limit(size=4000)
N = 1e7; 
df <- data.frame( 
 x = c(1:N), 
 y = sample(letters, N, replace =T), 
 z = sample( as.Date(sample(c(1:2000), N, replace=T), origin="1970-01-01")),
 w = factor( sample(c(1:N/10) , N, replace=T))   )

df[1:10,]
dff <- as.ffdf(df)
head(dff)
#str(dff)

save.ffdf(dff, dir = "dframeffdf")
dim(dff)
# on disk, the directory "dframeffdf" is : 205 MB (215.706.264 bytes)

### resetting R :: fresh RStudio Session 
dir1 <- 'P:/Projects/RLargeData';
setwd(dir1);
library(ff)
library(ffbase)
memory.size() # 15.63 
load.ffdf(dir = "dframeffdf")
memory.size() # 384.42
gc()
memory.size() # 287
```

So we have into memory 384 Mb, and after gc() there are 287, which is around the size of the data in the disk. (checked also in "Process explorer" application for windows)

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ffbase_0.7-1 ff_2.2-10    bit_1.1-9
```

***[END SECOND EDIT ]***

Comment: what type of data are you using? can you show us a couple of lines?

Comment: A couple of lines of code would help here. Have you tried out save.ffdf(yourffdf, anotherffdf). Are you sure you did not save other objects which are in RAM in "data.f"...

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the answers. I added (edit) a few lines of code in the question post. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code. How did you obtain the memory size and what type of data is in ffdf[5]

Comment: The code to have the memory comes from : sapply( ls(), function(x) object.size(x)).

Comment: The type of data are all factors (ramclass).

Comment: if you use object.size, you put all your data in RAM. No wonder it looks like the size of your in-RAM dataframe (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900898/why-does-ff-still-store-data-in-ram)

Comment: great, thank you, and sorry for not having seen the post you link, but no search result pointed to that. Problem solved. Question Answered !!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ff, when you have factor columns, the factor levels are always in RAM. ff character columns currently don't exist and character columns are converted to factors in an ffdf.

Regarding your example: your 'w' column in 'dff' contains more than 6 Mio levels. These levels are all in RAM. If you wouldn't have columns with a lot of levels, you wouldn' see the RAM increase as shown below using your example.

```
N = 1e7; 
df <- data.frame( 
 x = c(1:N), 
 y = sample(letters, N, replace =T), 
 z = sample( as.Date(sample(c(1:2000), N, replace=T), origin="1970-01-01")),
 w = sample(c(1:N/10) , N, replace=T))   
dff <- as.ffdf(df)
save.ffdf(dff, dir = "dframeffdf")

### resetting R :: fresh RStudio Session 
library(ff)
library(ffbase)
memory.size() # 14.67
load.ffdf(dir = "dframeffdf")
memory.size() # 14.78
```

Comment: Great, that explains every thing. Thank you. Is there a way to have a database with for example 4 millions of unique "ids" in the form "xs23134" and 40 million obs, and not going into RAM? perhaps converting those one to integers? As you say any character will be converted into factor and that into RAM... Any suggestion on how to deal with that?

Comment: Yes, convert it to an integer. See ?ikey in ffbase which does this for you and after that, you can remove your factor. And think about if you realy need your character column in your analytical exercise (my experience is that you hardly need these in data mining exercises but only for linking afterwards back to your database)

Comment: I see... yes, it is a good idea, and i have been applying that in the past. The problem is that in my "editing data" part of the coding, i have hundreds and hundreds  of lines like that (general coding): if( id = "sc1234" ) .... if(diagnose like "X12WS..." then ....) etc. So coding all the factors as integers gives the problem of not "seeing" what you are doing... That is why i wanted to keep character fields. Once data are edited, in the analysis part, i use to pass from factors to integers, to improve speed.

Answer (score 0):

The ffdf package(s) have mechanisms for segregating object in 'physical' and 'virtual' storage. I suspect you are implicitly constructing items in physical memory, but since you offer not coding for how this workspace was created, there's only so much guessing that is possible.

Comment: Hi , thank you for the answer. I added (edit) a few lines of code in the question post. Hope this helps.